# How to restore previously committed(but NOT deleted) files in local git project

Tags: git, gitlab

I had a local project directory(with some source files) which I tried to push to a new blank gitlab repo and ran into trouble. Actually for pushing the local files to the gitlab repo, I ran few git commands on local directory and now all the source src files have disappeared from the local directory. can anyone help me in suggesting for restoring those files please?  Below are the commands I ran in the directory in given order which caused the files to disappear.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add existing project files prior to the push to GitHub."  ###This actually committed all the source files
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<project.git>
### Till this point the command line was showing (master) i.e master branch in bracket
git branch -M develop
git push -uf origin develop ## error: failed to push some ref ...
git push -u origin develop ## error: failed to push some refs to ...
git pull
git push -u origin develop ## error: failed to push some refs to ...
git push ## fatal: The current branch develop has no upstream branch ..
git push --set-upstream origin develop ## error: failed to push some refs to ...
git pull https://gitlab.com/ielts-cmds/IELTS-CMDS-services-grp/cmds-circuit-breaker.git develop    ## * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD  .... fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

git checkout feature/initial ## switched to another branch..

etc. etc.
```

Please note, I did NOT run any remove or delete command so I am guessing those files are there somewhere in the local git references. And I cannot go back to the very initial 'master' branch now. Please help !

Comment: Can you try running `git checkout master`?

Comment: When you say "new blank gitlab repo" do you mean actually blank? Or did you create the project with a default README? Based on what I'm seeing, it looks like you actually already have files in the repo, which is why your pushes are getting rejected (because your local repo doesn't have the remote history)... but none of the commands you showed should result in files disappearing. Maybe you ran something else that did that? `git checkout develop` or `git checkout master` may get you back to where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the actual error output, which would be helpful in diagnosing the more basic "what went wrong" problem, but we *can* say why `git checkout master` is not working: you simply don't have a branch named `master`.  You have one named `develop`.  You can switch the name back to `master` if you like.

> ```
> git init
> git add .
> git commit -m "Add existing project files prior to the push to GitHub."
> ###This actually committed all the source files
>
> git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/<project.git>
> ### Till this point the command line was showing (master)
>     i.e master branch in brackets
> git branch -M develop
> ```

The last operation above changed the (local) *branch name* from `master` to `develop`.  (Note: it's safer in general to use `-m`, i.e., lowercase `m`, to avoid deleting an existing branch name by mistake.  But if `git init` created a new *empty* repository, as seems likely, then there were no other branch names and this could not have harmed anything.)

> ```
> git push -uf origin develop ## error: failed to push some ref ...
> ```

This *probably should have worked*, and knowing what the actual error output was might help.  My guess is that there was an additional message, prefixed with `remote:`, during which GitLab was telling you something important.

> ```
> git push -u origin develop ## error: failed to push some refs to ...
> ```

Given the failure *with* `--force` (`-f` is the same flag, just spelled with fewer characters), it's not surprising that the push *without* `--force` would also fail.

> ```
> git pull
> ```

Did this work?  It would be surprising if it did, given that you then say:

> ```
> git push ## fatal: The current branch develop has no upstream branch ..
> ```

since `git pull` with no additional options *also* requires that the current branch have an upstream set (the `git fetch` step would be able to run, but the *second* command that `git pull` runs requires an upstream).

> ```
> git pull https://gitlab.com/ielts-cmds/IELTS-CMDS-services-grp/cmds-circuit-breaker.git develop
> ## * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD  ....
> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
> ```

This output tells me that `ielts-cmds/IELTS-CMDS-services-grp/cmds-circuit-breaker.git` does have a branch named `develop`.  I cannot access that repository myself, so I have no idea what other branch names it might have.

The commits that are *on* that repository's `develop` are now available in your own repository as well.  But the *history*—i.e., the set of commits—obtained by starting from their last `develop` commit and working backwards through all other commits is independent of the commit(s) on *your* branch named `develop`.  That's all fine, since *their* `develop` is *their* branch name; your `develop` is *your* name, and these need not denote the same set of commits at all.

> ```
> git checkout feature/initial ## switched to another branch..
> ```

This would just fail, given the output shown above.  You would still be on your own `develop`.

If you have not done anything to change the fact, your own commit(s) are still on your own `develop`.  To make this—that your `develop` is completely independent of *their* `develop`—less confusing, you might want to rename your own `develop`:

```
git branch -m develop my-develop
```

for instance.

Run `git branch` with no options, or with `-a`, to list your own branch names, or all names (your branch names plus any *remote-tracking names* your Git has created based on other repositories' branch names).  If there are no applicable Git commands other than the ones shown above, you will still have just the one branch named `develop` unless and until you rename it.

To fix the problem, read a good book on Git and learn what "related histories" means, and/or see, e.g., [How to repair a git history and correctly merge unrelated histories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58021154/1256452) and [What happens in git when you merge unrelated histories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61734449/1256452)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, @torek for your explanation and dan1st and sytech for commenting.
The solution which worked was git hard reset. So in the logs of git I found the commit ID where those files I committed. The git hard reset to that commit ID took the directory in its previous state i.e with all files restored.